# Extra x axis labels when using geom_bar on a subset of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I am creating stacked bar charts on subsets of data using a loop. I'm exporting one stacked bar chart for each variable for each school. Its all working successfully - each chart shows only the subset of data - except that the x axis continues to be labeled for every school. So I have a big long chart area with blanks, and a stacked bar chart over the school for which the data is subsetted.

Here is sample of my data:

```
label    variable    class    percent
SchoolA   Optimism    High     67
SchoolA   Optimism    Med      33
SchoolA   Optimism    Low      20
SchoolA   SelfEsteem  High     84
SchoolA   SelfEsteem  Med      12
SchoolA   SelfEsteem  Low      4
SchoolB   Optimism    High     60
SchoolB   Optimism    Med      21
SchoolB   Optimism    Low      19
SchoolB   SelfEsteem  High     20
SchoolB   SelfEsteem  Med      42
SchoolB   SelfEsteem  Low      38
```

...which carries on for several hundred more variables and schools.

In general I'm doing this:

**Create an array of values for each school and variable**

```
schools<-unique(df1$label)  
variables<-unique(df1$variable)
```

**Function that plots each subset of data as a stacked bar chart**

```
doPlot<-function(subdf){  
    ggplot(subdf,aes(x=label,y=percent,fill=factor(class)))+  
    geom_bar(stat="identity")}
```

**Runs doPlot using each subset of data**

```
for(i in 1:length(schools)){  
    for (j in 1:length(variables)){  
        subdf<-data.frame(subset(df1,label==schools[i]&variable==variables[j]))  
        doPlot(subdf)}}
```

Why is the chart creating and labeling an x-axis for the original data set and not only for the subset of data? I am a R newbie, but I've been searching and trying things out for a while and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you subset a dataframe with a factor column (`df1$label` is a factor with levels 'SchoolA' and 'SchoolB'), the `label` column still has multiple levels, even though there is currently only one unique label in it.

e.g.:

```
df2 <- subset(df1,label=='SchoolA'&variable=='Optimism')
df2$label
# [1] SchoolA SchoolA SchoolA
# Levels: SchoolA SchoolB
```

See how even though `df2$label` is 'SchoolA' only, there are still two levels? `ggplot` uses the levels to draw the graphs.

`?subset` mentions :

> Factors may have empty levels after subsetting; unused levels are
>        not automatically removed.  See ‘droplevels’ for a way to drop all
>        unused levels from a data frame.

Then going to `?droplevels`: "used to drop unused levels from .. factors in a data frame".

So try doing:

```
subdf <- droplevels(data.frame(subset(df1,label==schools[i]&variable==variables[j])))
```

Then you'll get just one variable on the x axis, the current school.

(As an aside - is a stacked bar chart the best way to represent these? In particular, I notice that SchoolA's 'Optimism' adds up to 120% overall, and the stacked bar chart seems to enforce this understanding of the data. If that's not how you want the data to be interpreted, perhaps you could consider a different way of presenting it?)

Comment: Thank you mathematical.coffee! Using droplevels solves it. Why we're creating stacked bar charts is a long story, and has been debated, but for the reports they're being fed into stacked bar charts seems to work. SchoolA's 'Optimism' adding up to 120% is a mistake in my dummy data - thanks for catching.